# How to sass --watch imported files from another directory?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to --watch for changes from scss files from one directory that I am @importing in another directory.

Is there any way to do this?

The imported files are being changed in their respective directory but are not being updated because (I presume) sass is looking for changes only from the directory I am watching from?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [WebPack](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/webpack/watch).  Which I'm guessing you're probably already using, one way or another?  "Sass" is just files written in a markup language.  It doesn't "watch" anything ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 Unfortunately, the way the project we are working on is set up, we can't really use webpack or even gulp. Curious though as to what you would suggest with WebPack?

Comment: So what *IS* your project using?  Based on the little information you've given, I'm willing to bet your project is already using webpack ... but you just don't realize it.  Could you give more details, please?

Comment: How are you "watching" your main SASS file to compile?

Comment: sass --watch scss/template.scss:css/template.css . The template.scss is importing files from another directory that DO get compiled correctly once updated, but ONLY when I re-run the sass --watch command manually each time. So the issue is with the @import not getting updated automatically without a manual sass --watch command after each change is made.